# Independent Probability 5 digit lock question

Tags: probability

I'm feeling quite confused about how to approach this problem. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Robin Hood attempts to gain access to a bank vault which is protected by a **5 digit** access code. He enters a **randomly** chosen sequence of 5 digits (where each chosen digit is **equally** likely to be any integer from **0 to 9**, **independently** of all other digits).

*Given that he got exactly two of the five digits right, what is the probability that the three middle digits wrong?*

Comment: In a more abstract sense, someone is picking 5 balls, 3 of which are red (incorrect) and two of which are blue (correct). What is the probability that the corresponding sequence is BRRRB? (It's one divided by the number of such sequences...)

Comment: so, from first principles, p(event) = no of ways event can happen/total number of outcomes. There is only 1 way to get BRRRB, and there are 5! different ways to get 5 balls out? so 1/(5!)?

Comment: No, you are given the fact that you draw 2 blue balls and 3 red balls. So a sequence like BBBBB or RRRRB is not allowed. The total number of outcomes here represents the number of 5-digit sequences with 3 of one type and 2 of a different type.

Comment: Oh so, 1/5C3 = 1/10 = 0.1, because I want to choose 3 red balls out of 5 trials.

Permutations and combinations are always so confusing. Like websites say, permutations, order matters, and combinations, order doesn't matter. Though I have no idea how that would relate to a question like this.

Can I ask how you think of permutations and combinations?

Comment: Nvm, I got it I think.

Say, we have 5 numbers, and we wanna find the different number of ways of re-arranging those 5 numbers. It would be permutation.

And if we want to find the number of ways we can pick 3 different numbers out of the 5, then it would be a combination.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The probability of choosing exactly two of the five digits right is,
$$\binom{5}{2} (.1)^2(.9)^3$$

Comment: That's more complicated than necessary. You don't need to use the 0.9 and 0.1 probabilities to get the answer.